# How do i compare current timestamp to the timestap from firebase flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, datetime, timestamp, compare

I want to create a function which does not allow the user to remove the appointment once the timestamp for the appointment has past already. But what i tried below does not work, i hope to get some guidance from you guys

My widget.filter is a var which has the timestamp value from firebase

```
DateTime currentPhoneDate = DateTime.now(); //DateTime
Timestamp myTimeStamp = Timestamp.fromDate(currentPhoneDate); //To TimeStamp
DateTime myDateTime = myTimeStamp.toDate(); // TimeStamp to DateTime

print("current phone data is: $currentPhoneDate");
print("current phone data is: $myDateTime");

if(myTimeStamp < widget.filter){
print('work');
 }else{
 print('fail');
 }
```

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by "does not work"?  Does it print `fail`?  You have not shown what output you're observing.  What is the type of `widget.filter`?  What is its value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  DateTime currentPhoneDate = DateTime.now();
  Timestamp myTimeStamp = Timestamp.fromDate(currentPhoneDate);
  DateTime myDateTime = myTimeStamp.toDate();

  print("myTimeStamp is: $myTimeStamp");
  print("currentPhoneDate is: $currentPhoneDate");
  print("myDateTime is: $myDateTime");

  //  if widget.filter DataType is not Timestamp then first convert it to Timestamp.

  if (myTimeStamp.millisecondsSinceEpoch <
      widget.filter.millisecondsSinceEpoch) {
    print('work');
  } else {
    print('fail');
  }
```